# Adding label to whole group of drainage features using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.2 Bonn and have a lot stuff imported from Google Earth.

Am I able to create a group of all drainages and label them with one click, or do I need to choose/select a new one each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drainages are all in one layer, you can label them all at once. If not, you can label one according to your needs, then save that style as a qml (button is on the lower left in the `style`-tab of the layers properties) and load it for all the other layers.

Comment: Hmm alrighty, but My question is if i have all them grupped like 10 Drainages from  this area, 10 from another every in diffirent group created, can i just choose groupe and change Style (Labels), Thanks Erik for helping me again :D

Comment: As in "grouped but in the same layer"? Then there should be some attribute to identify them by, and you may use this attribute to use `classified`-styling/labelling.